# How to pass properties to chocolatey version of psake

Tags: psake, chocolatey

I've installed psake using Chocolatey. This allows you to run psake using the `psake` command from either powershell or the windows command line.

However when I try and pass properties to psake using the following command

```
psake TestProperties -properties @{"tags"="test"}
```

I get the following error:

```
PS D:\projects\WebTestAutomation> psake TestProperties -properties @{"tags"="test"}
"& 'C:\Chocolatey\lib\psake.4.2.0.1\tools\\psake.ps1' TestProperties -properties System.Collections.Hashtable
C:\Chocolatey\lib\psake.4.2.0.1\tools\psake.ps1 : Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'properties'. Cannot convert the "System.Collections.Hashtable" value of
 type "System.String" to type "System.Collections.Hashtable".
At line:1 char:80
+ & 'C:\Chocolatey\lib\psake.4.2.0.1\tools\\psake.ps1' TestProperties -properties <<<<  System.Collections.Hashtable; if ($psake.build_success -eq $false) { exit 1 } else { e
xit 0 }
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [psake.ps1], ParameterBindin...mationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentTransformationError,psake.ps1
```

Any ideas on how overcome this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved this by passing the properties `Hashtable` as a `string`.

```
psake TestProperties -properties "@{tags='test'}"
```

I'd also recommend running the command from the command prompt as opposed to powershell. Because the `psake` command works by calling a `.bat` file, which then calls a `.cmd` which in turn executes a `.ps1` file, using ampersands in the properties caused issues when the command was execute from powershell.

For example the following command succesfully runs from the command prompt but errors when run from the powershell console:

```
psake TestProperties -properties "@{tags='test^&wip'}"
```

Note the use of `^` to escape the `&` character.